# How to create a configurable Asynctimeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to set a configurable timeout value for my AsyncController. I am aware that we can decorate a method with the `[AsyncTimeout(5000)]` attribute and we are also able to use the value with a const variable. I would like to use a static variable so that I can have a more configurable way to set the timeout after compilation.

Reading this [AsyncManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.async.asyncmanager.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx) it seems that there is a property called timeout that can be set.

Here is what I have tried.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void DoWorkAsync(MyQuery query)
    {
        AsyncManager.Timeout = TestTimeout; //TestTimeout is a static int set to 120000
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        (do work)...
    }
```

It seems that the AsyncManager.Timeout value is not being used and instead throwing the TimeoutException after the default 45 seconds.

Is there a way to set this timeout value at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create class derived from `AsyncTimeoutAttribute` like this

```
public class CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute : AsyncTimeoutAttribute
{
    public CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute() : base(Params.TimeOut)
    {}       
}
```

where `Params.Timeout` contains your static timeout variable.

Or you can try this (just copy/paste base `AsyncTimeout` functionality):

```
public class CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute : AsyncTimeoutAttribute
{
    public CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute() : base(0)
    {}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        var managerContainer = filterContext.Controller as IAsyncManagerContainer;
        if (managerContainer == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation has timed out.");
        managerContainer.AsyncManager.Timeout = //There you can get your timeout parameter from resourse (i.e. config file, database, etc);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Also, you should mark your action method with `async` keywork, your method should return `Task` or `Task<T>`, and last parameter of your method should be `CancellationToken`, otherwise `AsyncTimeout` doesn't work.

For example:

```
[CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute]
public async Task PerformAction(/*Some parameters*/, CancellationToken token)
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it seems to be working great. Thanks!

Comment: The second solution did not work for me; the parameter should come from the backend (CMS).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to inherit from AsyncTimeoutAttribute. Just create your own CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute and inherit it directly from ActionFilterAttribute. Otherwise base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext) will override yours and you will surely have TimeoutException, as you send 0 in the base constructor.

Here is how you achieve it.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAsyncTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        }

        var managerContainer = filterContext.Controller as IAsyncManagerContainer;
        if (managerContainer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("CustomAsyncTimeout Action Filter failed");
        }

        var duration = GetYouDurationAsYouWish();
        if (duration < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(duration));
        }

        managerContainer.AsyncManager.Timeout = duration;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```